# Can I have SEO friendly urls in Struts?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, seo, struts

I want to have SEO friendly urls in my application, which will be built in java/j2ee using Struts (1/2).

I have some classifications as follows

```
county/countryname
county/state/statename
county/state/locality/localitname
```

I guess above URLs will be seo friendly?

How can I have such URLs with Struts instead of something like `/county='xyz'` ?

Comment: Please check the wonderful Play! Framework at http://www.playframework.org/. I think you will like it.

Comment: i had tried play framework. but i dont think its stable like ror or django ,so i dont think it can be used for large webapp

Comment: @qeek : Can you please suggest me, play looks good, but am not sure if it can be used for big webapp.Is it stable? please comment

Comment: See here: http://www.playframework.org/community/testimonials 
I guess it's as stable as Java in the end :)

Answer (score 3):

use [urlrewrite](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) library, it will integrate nicely with most of the java web frameworks.

example from [here](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/2.6/):

> In the following example requests for
>   `/world/usa/nyc` will be transparently
>   forwarded to
>   `/world.jsp?country=usa&city=nyc`
>
> ```
> <rule enabled="true">
>    <from>^/world/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$</from>
>    <to>/world.jsp?country=$1&amp;city=$2</to>
> </rule>
> ```

Comment: Yes, its just a filter, that needs to be added in web.xml.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html), it will convert your URLs like `http://myapp.com/u/nishant/page/account/tab/3` to `http://myapp.com?u=nishant&page=account&tab=3`. So, your app don't need to worry about how URL structure.

Alternatively, you may use [URLRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/), which is nothing but a cleverly written filter that need to the first filter of your application and all the requests should pass through this. It follows the same pattern rules as Apache mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done with Struts. You'll need Filters in order to achieve this.