# Passing parameters in URL without query string in Struts 2

Tags: java, parameters, struts2, url-parameters, wildcard-mapping

I want to use URLs like

`host/ActionName/123/abc/`

instead of passing query string like

`host/ActionName?parm1=123&parm2=abc`

How can I do that in Struts 2?

I done as below but it is not working, showing 500 error code

```xml
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>

<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <action name="/action/*"
    class="gov.apiic.serviceRequest.action.ServiceRequest" method="method" >
    <param name="p1">{1}</param>
    <result name="success">views.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Comment: Its called  SEO friendly URL and u can find answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5443736/1085285 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/5762548/1085285

Comment: Thank you very much for your response . I done some effort but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not possible with plain Struts2 under the 2.1+. As a workaround you can do this with [UrlRewriter filter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). From Struts2 2.1+ with the help of wildcards you can use something like `host/ActionNmae/param1-123/param2-abc` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484392/struts2-wildcard-action-mapping-with-dummy-data) post, but not like `host/ActionNmae/123/abc/`. The difference is that in the second case there's no parameter names. The workaround is to use [Parameters after the action name](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/wildcard-mappings.html#parameters-after-the-action-name).

```
@Action(value = "/ActionNmae/*/*", params = {"param1", "{1}", "param2", "{2}"}
```

Comment: Yes, you can, with the pattern matcher mapper (I forget what it's called).

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the [`namedVariable`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/wildcard-mappings.html#WildcardMappings-Parametersinnamespaces) or [`regex`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/wildcard-mappings.html#WildcardMappings-AdvancedWildcards) pattern matchers.

Each has its own advantages and disadvantages, most of which can be worked around.