# How to apply a global dynamic result path prefix in Struts 2?

Tags: jsp, struts2, actionresult, wildcard-mapping, struts2-namespace

I have a website using Struts2 as the MVC framework.  I need to re-skin the JSPs.  I need to have the old JSPs accessible alongside the new JSPs.  So I have added a root folder of `/newdesign/` and copied all of the existing JSP folders into it.

So, if I login with the name/value pair `?newdesign=true` (for example) I'm the initial request then I can:

1. Store this in the user's session and then
2. Dynamically add `/newdesign/` as a global prefix to the `<result>` tag in `struts.xml` that determines if the new or old JSP is loaded for the related `Action`.

This way the developer can check if all the old page has been re-skinned into a new page.

How can I do part 2 above?

I have looked at using

`struts.convention.result.path = /newdesign`

but this is not dynamic and I cannot change it if the user is to be shown the old or new JSPs.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the part 1 then assume you could set the parameter to the action that should redirect to the appropriate action of the other packages that contain the namespace that is corresponding to your parameter `newdesign`.

The prefix to the action name is  used in the URL to specify the namespace to separate actions in packages. So, the `newdesign` is going to the separate module by different namespace.

Now you have two modules that has the same action names and results but different locations that depends on namespace. You should configure them in different packages that have their own namespaces. There's an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-namespace-configuration-example-and-explanation/) that would let you better understand the namespaces concept.

To simplify your packages configuration you can use a parameter in namespace via [wildcard mappings](http://struts.apache.org/core-developers/wildcard-mappings.html#parameters-in-namespaces).

Comment: Many thanks for your fast reply...I have ~40 actions with a total of ~100 <result> tags so I don't want to duplicate the struts config since I am also merging code from developers who are updating the original actions.  I only need to re-skin the JSPs so only need to change the path to them to eg '/newdesign/jsp/admin/login.jsp' (instead of '/jsp/admin/login.jdp') based on a Session variable.  So additional namespace and separate actions is not a preferred solution.  Do you know a way I can globally add such a 'result' prefix?

Comment: I found a way to add a variable into the <result> tag via EL - http://mycodefixes.blogspot.co.il/2010/10/struts-2-creating-dynamic-results.html But I still have to update the JSP paths in any <%@include file="/jsp/include.jsp"%> inside of my JSPs!  This further complicates my need of having both old-skinned JSPs and new-skinned JSPs being available together.  So I am abandaonning this idea. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: EL is a bad solution with Strurs2, results could have dynamic parameters. With include you should use `<s:url` tag that could also be parametrized. This is nothing complicated like an ice-cake but needs to get you involved in the process by Struts. Why you didn't satisfied with the wildcard solution? If you needs more explanation you might look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411736/passing-parameters-in-url-without-query-string-in-struts2/14415902#14415902) answer and prepare digging the Struts2 docs.