# Implement generic type for boiler plate code

Tags: java, struts2

I have struts based application in which I wrote a method which authenticate user,after authentication it redirects to the `dashboard.action`,in my application there are 3 or more modules like `uploaddocument.action`, `reportsection.action`, `downloaddocument.action`.

I want to make this code generic so user can gain directly access from any of the page, currently it is implemented only in `loginaction`, that means if user tries to access action other than dashboard, he will encounterd and an unauthorized error.

In order to allow user gain access from any where,I will need to write three more action classes and implement the same method, because each time i need to return `"success"` and on behalf of that I will redirect the action to their intended action class.

So I want to avoid the same. I am looking for some sort of generic implementation which make this method universal and I don't need to write three more classes, this will avoid the lots of boiler plate code.

**FLOW**

```
hit localhost:8080/lcsd--->authenticatAD()--success--> dashboard.action
```

**REQUIREMENT:**

```
hit localhost:8080/lcsd/upload--->authenticatAD()--success--> uploaddocument.action


  hit localhost:8080/lcsd/report--->authenticatAD()--success--> reportdocument.action


 hit localhost:8080/lcsd/download--->authenticatAD()--success--> downloaddocument.action
```

**the method define below:-**

```
public String authenticateAD() {
        logger.debug("Start authenticateAD=" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        setPage("login");
        setRole("login");
        boolean validate = true;
        userId = getServletRequest().getRemoteUser();
        if (userId == null) {
            return "error";
        }
        if (userId.lastIndexOf("\\") > 0) {
            userId = userId.substring(userId.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1).trim();
        }
        logger.debug("UserId=" + userId);
        if (validate) {
            LDAPIntegration authentication = new LDAPIntegration();
            String group = "";
            try {
                List<String> groupList = new ArrayList();
                groupList = authentication.getUserGroups(userId);
                String role = "";
                if ((groupList != null) && (!groupList.isEmpty())) {
                    List<String> interList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < groupList.size(); i++) {
                        group = groupList.get(i);
                        logger.info("groupList group:" + group);
                        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(group);
                        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                            if (st.countTokens() == 1) {
                                interList.add(st.nextToken());
                            } else {
                                st.nextToken();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Collections.sort(interList);
                    logger.info("Sorted InnerList of Role: " + interList.toString());
                    if (interList.contains("Administrators"))
                        role = "Administrators";
                    else if (interList.contains("Operators"))
                        role = "Operators";
                    else if (interList.contains("Guests") && interList.size() == 1)
                        role = "Guests";
                    else
                        for (int j = 0; j < interList.size(); j++) {
                            if (!interList.get(j).equalsIgnoreCase("Guests"))
                                role = interList.get(j);
                        }
                    for (int k = 0; k < groupList.size(); k++) {
                        if (!groupList.get(k).contains("Administrators") || !groupList.get(k).contains("Operators")
                                || !groupList.get(k).contains("Guests"))
                            group = groupList.get(k);
                    }
                    /* group = (String)groupList.get(0); */
                    logger.debug("groupList group:" + group);
                    /*
                     * StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(group); while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                     * if (st.countTokens() == 1) { role = st.nextToken(); } else { st.nextToken();
                     * } }
                     */
                } else {
                    throw new CustomException("INVALID_USER");
                }
                if (!role.toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase("Administrators".toLowerCase()))
                    if (!role.toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase("Operators".toLowerCase()))
                        if (!role.toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase("Guests".toLowerCase())) {
                            if (group.toLowerCase().indexOf("area manager".toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                                String areaName = null;
                                List<String> areaNameList = new ArrayList();

                                for (int i = 0; i < groupList.size(); i++) {
                                    group = (String) groupList.get(i);
                                    if (group.toLowerCase().indexOf("area manager".toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                                        logger.debug("areamanager groupList group:" + group);
                                        if (group.toLowerCase().contains("area manager-")) {
                                            areaName = group
                                                    .substring(group.indexOf("Download Area") + 14, group.length())
                                                    .trim();
                                        } else {
                                            areaName = group
                                                    .substring(group.indexOf("Area Manager") + 12, group.length())
                                                    .trim();
                                        }

                                        logger.info("areaName:" + areaName);
                                        if (areaName != null) {
                                            areaNameList.add(areaName);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                logger.debug("areaNameList===" + areaNameList);
                                setArea(areaNameList);
                                role = "area manager";
                            } else {
                                throw new CustomException("INVALID_ROLE");
                            }
                        }
                setUserGroup(groupList);
                logger.info("authenticateAD groupList: " + groupList);
                logger.info("authenticateAD Role: " + role);
                logger.info("authenticateAD userId: " + userId);
                setRole(role);
                setUser(userId);
                logger.info("Get Methods in authenticateAD !!");
                logger.info("authenticateAD Role: " + getRole());
                logger.info("authenticateAD user: " + getUser());
                logger.info("authenticateAD userId: " + getUserId());
                logger.info("authenticateAD group List: " + getUserGroup().toString());
                logger.debug("Get Methods in authenticateAD !!");
                logger.debug("authenticateAD Role: " + getRole());
                logger.debug("authenticateAD user: " + getUser());
                logger.debug("authenticateAD userId: " + getUserId());
                logger.debug("authenticateAD group List: " + getUserGroup().toString());
                logger.debug("End authenticateAD=" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                return "success";
            } catch (CustomException e) {
                logger.error("error in authenticateAD ", e);
                if (e.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("NETWORK_ERROR")) {
                    addActionError(manager.getValue("login.network.error"));
                } else if (e.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("INVALID_USER")) {
                    addActionError(manager.getValue("login.invalid.user"));
                } else if (e.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("INVALID_ROLE")) {
                    addActionError(manager.getValue("login.invalid.role"));
                }
            }
        }

        return "error";
    }
```

Comment: What is the `generic` part of the method you have displayed? Only the `setPage/setRole` commands?

Comment: currently I have only those two

Comment: see the flow in my edits

Comment: You should add a Service Layer, and in the Action call the service that authenticates users

Comment: Why wouldn't the authentication be handled by an interceptor? Or a base action class?

Comment: Fabio, I do understand what you are saying, I will introduce service layer, but still I need to write three classes to redirect to three actions

Comment: Agree with Dave, but its a legacy project running since 2006-07

Comment: I think that it is fine to have 3 different actions for 3 different pages. You could create a base action for authentication, and the 3 actions that you need extend that base action.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48434820/573032