# Struts2.0 show message/username different way

Tags: jsp, struts2

In Java Struts2.0, we can use this way to show username

in Action:

```
String username;

String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
```

in jsp

```
<s:property value="username"/>
```

that use `<s:property>` for getting username from action, but if i want to use it for other way, is that any possible I can get username by myself, like can i get username by actionurl/username or some other way from url? like if you enter actionurl/username the page just print username? or any other way possible？

Comment: The question isn't clear at all. You can get the username from the URL using normal parameters or one of the matcher-style pattern matchers etc. To *expose* a property to a JSP page it needs to be either a normal JSP-scoped attribute, or an action property, or a model property if you're using ModelDriven.

Comment: Other way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411736/passing-parameters-in-url-without-query-string-in-struts2/14415902#14415902

Comment: You mean access it directly from the request? Try the request scope (#request.something). When trying to figure out OGNL expressions it is good to use s:property tags and apply ".class" to the end of the expression, that way you can figure out what type you are working with. For instance when working with the request you might think you should be getting a String but are really getting a String[], ".class" will guide the way.