# how to fetch params defined in the action url in Interceptor

Tags: java, url, struts2, struts2-interceptors

I have defined an action in struts.xml like this

```
<action name="*/*/execute" class="com.test.project1.abc" method="execute">
        <param name="username">{1}</param>
        <param name="resource">{2}</param>
```

How can i fetch the values of username and resource in interceptor ?

I have fetched these values in the action class "com.test.project1.abc" using

```
ActionContext context = ActionContext.getContext();
Map<String, Object> params = context.getParameters();
```

However the above does not yield results in an interceptor. So how should i fetch the params in this case ?

Comment: What does your interceptor stack look like?

Comment: Use parameters after the action name, not before. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14415902/573032) answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext();
    Map<String,Object> reqParams = (Map<String,Object>)context.get(ActionContext.PARAMETERS);

    /**
    * Your logic
    */

    return invocation.invoke();
}
```

Comment: but why is ActionContext.getContext().getParameters() returning the query parameters and not the url parameters in interceptor ?

Comment: @SivakamiSubbu can you please share your interceptor-stack ?